# Scheduling Automatic Backups for Virtual Private Web Server running CENTOS 6.3 and WHM

Tags: centos, backup

I'm pretty new to administering my own VPS - but thus far am finding it quite a compelling experience. There's something quite refreshing about having complete control over everything it does.

One thing that I would like to look at is a suitable backup solution (a few times a day).

My current setup is as follows:

I'm running a CENTOS 6.3 VPS with a single 25GB hard drive solely for the purpose of hosting websites. I'm using WHM & cPanel for administering them.

I now plan on adding an additional hard disk and hooking it up to my VPS. What I'm not sure about is how I get the two disks talking and get the backup process going. I'm not a seasons SSH-er so don't really know where to start.

I'm hosting with Serverlove (one of the best hosting providers I've used) and am provided with a number of unique identifiers for each hard disk so I imagine these may play a part in linking them together.

I appreciate that this is a little vague (I'm clutching at straws) but any assistance is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the cPanel/WHM documentation http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/ConfigBackup it will explain how to create backups for your accounts on your VPS/dedicated server.

Note: It is best to have backups stored on a different machine or even datacenter.

Comment: Thanks! Thought it would be more complicated than that. One thing I'm still not clear about is how to make it backup to the other mounted drive. I've followed the instructions as per the http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/AllFAQ/BackupFAQ#I%20want%20to%20run%20backups%20on%20a%20mount but can't see a way of referencing this drive in the backup configuration.

Comment: @OliverFarrell for this to happen, you need to use the mount point (is the drive mounted?) If so, it should be in the form of something like `/some/path/on/your/vps/` Typically in my setup I mount the hard drive `/dev/sdb` (where sdb is the name of your hd) as `/backup`. This allows me to `cd` into `/backup` which is really `/dev/sdb` You would put `/backup` under the field **Backup Destination** in `Home »Backup »Configure Backup`

Comment: Wahay! Got it working. Ended up prodding around in fdisk to mount the drive and create a partition. Thanks for giving me a nudge in the right direction @Adam!

Comment: @OliverFarrell yup np. Just remember to vote on the answer - seems like you are new StackExchange family.